# Insert/append multiple records incrementing each by 1, starting with the max pre-existing

Tags: ms-access, append

So, I have a table with a number field as a key. As records are added this field increases by one for each. Records are then sometimes deleted, leaving a sequence similar to 1,2,5,6,8,9,13, etc. New records are always added as one higher than the previous largest number in the sequence. I'm in a situation where I need to insert about 9000 new records via append query, but the append always applies the same next-highest number all the new records. Below is what I've got at the moment, the bit labeled "Expr1" is an illustration as best I can manage of what I'd like it to do.

```
INSERT INTO ALTSTRAT ( ALT_STRAT_ID, FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3, FIELD4, FIELD5 )
SELECT Max(ALT_STRAT_ID)+1 AS Expr1, "PROM" AS Expr2, 
ITEM.ITM_NUM, "@" AS Expr3, ITEM.MASTER_STRAT, 0 AS Expr4
FROM ITEM
GROUP BY "PROM", ITEM.ITM_NUM, "@", ITEM.MASTER_STRAT, 0;
```

Any help is much appreciated, I don't have much hair left to tear out. Thanks!

Comment: First, use an autonumber field. Second, an autonumber PK is only meant to uniquely identify records and should not have any meaning outside a table. So if there's gaps in an autonumber field, well, that's perfectly OK.

Comment: @WolfgangKais Rene's comment is fine. It does not answer the question, it just provides a comment saying this problem might not need solving.

Comment: Thanks very much for the responses. Unfortunately, the field is not an Autonumber, just Number, and I don't have the ability to change that. Under normal circumstances, this table is maintained via an interface with a GUI web app, one record at a time. That method only ever adds a record with an ALT_STRAT_ID one number higher than the previous max value. I want to stay as consistent with that as I can when doing this kind of direct maintenance for fear that I might inadvertently screw something up if I don't.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `ALT_STRAT_ID` actually *is* an AutoNumber. Thus, simply omit this when inserting - it will ad up automatically - and no need to Group By the constant values:

```
INSERT INTO ALTSTRAT 
    ( FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3, FIELD4, FIELD5 )
SELECT 
    "PROM" AS Expr2, ITEM.ITM_NUM, "@" AS Expr3, ITEM.MASTER_STRAT, 0 AS Expr4
FROM 
    ITEM
GROUP BY 
    ITEM.ITM_NUM, ITEM.MASTER_STRAT;
```